# Appium - Getting error "This socket has been ended by the other party" while doing parallel execution on real devices

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

Our aim is to run test scripts on 5 physical devices parallel. We are initiating appium server with 5 different ports and all 5 devices are connected in one USB hub.

If we do initiate after switching OFF devices and then switch ON it works fine for one time.

But when we run it again then it starts throwing error "This socket has been ended by the other party".

We have tried "--suppress-adb-kill-server" while initiating appium server, but it's still keep closing apps on devices. Test scripts run properly on one device only.

Error Logs:

```
Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[Appium] Had trouble ending session 514a0afc-a0e7-4205-ba39-ac93650bac9d: Android bootstrap socket crashed: Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionFinished' logged at 1560747742093 (10:32:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Android bootstrap socket crashed: Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at Socket.socketClient.on.err (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/bootstrap.js:97:21)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at Socket.emit (events.js:193:13)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:406:8)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at write (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/bootstrap.js:122:25)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at Promise._execute (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:313:9)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at new Promise (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at AndroidBootstrap.sendCommand (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/bootstrap.js:118:18)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at AndroidBootstrap.sendCommand [as shutdown] (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/bootstrap.js:173:18)
[debug] [W3C (514a0afc)]     at AndroidDriver.shutdown [as deleteSession] (/home/palashjain/node-v11.14.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/driver.js:412:28)
```

Please let me know if you need any more info to understand the issue.